# Check if all percentages in the array were shown

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using this Code to show the current progress in my progressbar:

```
var rotatingTextElement;
var rotatingText = new Array();
var ctr = 0;

function initRotateText() {
rotatingTextElement = document.getElementById("percent");
rotatingText[0] = rotatingTextElement.innerHTML;
rotatingText[1] = "5%";
rotatingText[2] = "10%";
rotatingText[3] = "15%";
rotatingText[4] = "20%";
rotatingText[5] = "25%";
rotatingText[6] = "30%";
rotatingText[7] = "35%";
rotatingText[8] = "40%";
rotatingText[9] = "45%";
rotatingText[10] = "50%";
rotatingText[11] = "55%";
rotatingText[12] = "60%";
rotatingText[13] = "65%";
rotatingText[14] = "70%";
rotatingText[15] = "75%";
rotatingText[16] = "80%";
rotatingText[17] = "85%";
rotatingText[18] = "90%";
rotatingText[19] = "95%";
rotatingText[20] = "100%";
setInterval(rotateText, 500);
}
function rotateText() {
ctr++;
if(ctr >= rotatingText.length) {
ctr = 0;
}
rotatingTextElement.innerHTML = rotatingText[ctr];
}
window.onload = initRotateText;
```

It basicly writs a new percentage in span#percent every 500 miliseconds. 
The problem is that after the progressbar has reached 100% it starts again with 0%, 5% and so on.
How can I check if the percentages in the array rotatingText till [20] were all shown and then stop the rotation?

Comment: Wow, what an array. `(ctr*5)+"%"` anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Do this instead:

```
var rotatingTextElement = document.getElementById("percent");
var ctr = 0;

function rotateText() {
  rotatingTextElement.innerHTML = ctr + "%";
  ctr += 5;
  if (ctr <= 100) {
    window.setTimeout(rotateText, 500);
  }
}

rotateText();
```

Comment: I meant to clean my response up to this point and got distracted.  Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can tidy this up.  To answer your question, start by assigning the interval to a variable:

```
var rotator = null;
...
rotator = setInterval(rotateText, 500);

...

function rotateText() {
  ctr++;
  if(ctr >= rotatingText.length -1) {
    clearInterval(rotator);
  }
  rotatingTextElement.innerHTML = rotatingText[ctr];
}
...
```

Then instead of resetting the iterator to 0 when it goes out of bounds, clear the interval so it stops changing the value.  You'll need to add the -1 so that it stops on `rotatingText[length-1]` (the last element)